# Django 1.8: Migrations not detected after deleting migrations folder

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I accidentally deleted the migrations folder and now python manage.py makemigrations does not detect the changes in my models. What do I do?

```
shubham@shubham-PC:~/Documents/try/ecommerce$ python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

The repository is [here](https://github.com/ShubhamRathi/Django-ecommerce)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try with `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`.

**Edit:** Django allows you to have apps without migrations within your projects. This is detected with the `migrations` folder. If an app does not have it, it won't create the migrations when using the `python manage.py makemigrations` command although you have it in `INSTALLED_APPS`. To force an application to work with migrations you need to specify the name of the application. Btw, this is not necessary for applications you create with new versions of Django because they are created with the `migrations` folder. This is only necessary when you remove the migrations folder (as you did) or when working with applications created with older versions of Django.

Comment: That worked! 
Do you have any idea why python manage.py makemigrations did not detect changes?

Comment: I've edited the answer since the explanation was too long to fit in the comment ;).

Comment: Bravo! Explains everything!

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you sir.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But for some reason , i think even newer versions have that issue. I have version 3.1.5 and i faced a similar issue. If i delete all the files in the migration folder ( but not delete the folder itself ) , the same issue happens.