# Does makemigrations in django recreates existing tables for a reason?

Tags: django

I wanted to validate if there is a bug in makemigrations in django 1.8 with sql lite  or I am doing something wrong.

1. After I Dropped my DB and deleted all migration folders. I run

> ```
> python manage.py makemigrations 
> python manage.py migrate
> ```

DB gets created no problems.

2.I have to modify existing model in one of the apps (app abc)
I perform my change and run again

> ```
> python manage.py makemigrations
> ```

3.it doesn't find any changes

then I run same thing again but with app name

> ```
> python manage.py makemigrations abc
> ```

4.It does some updates in migrations , I believe it recreates all the tables and not just my change **!!!!**

5.Then I execute

> `python manage.py migrate`

and getting error that table already exists .

**Is it a bug in django framework  or I am doing something wrong and there is a reason why it behaves this way?**

Copy paste from my shell starting from step 2:

```
    (mrp) C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

(mrp) C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src>python manage.py makemigrations purchase
Migrations for 'purchase':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model PO
    - Create model POmaterial

(mrp) C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: customer, manufacture, product, django_filters, a
utofixture, staticfiles, messages, smart_selects, watson, sales, item, django_co
untries, mptt, inventory, django_select2, production, main, crispy_forms
  Apply all migrations: purchase, vendor, sessions, admin, sites, flatpages, con
tenttypes, auth, registration
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying purchase.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init
__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init
__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.p
y", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.p
y", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\comman
ds\migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor
.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=f
ake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor
.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migratio
n.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, projec
t_state)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operatio
ns\models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schem
a.py", line 282, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schem
a.py", line 107, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
 line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
 line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97,
 in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
 line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\ba
se.py", line 316, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "purchase_po" already exists
```

Comment: Please paste complete error traceback

Comment: I pasted all the content of my shell.

Comment: by looking at your log. `0001_initial.py`. in step 3 actual migrations created for your app. have you deleted any migration files from step 1? if data is not important delete database and repeate above steps everything will work fine.

Comment: I am doing that now. It happens again and again so it is a pain to re  populate the DB every time. after i did python manage.py makemigrations  I havent deleted any folders and it didnt create any. now I manually try to add a migrations folders to each app root with __init__.py inside it

Comment: In step1 try to create makemigrations for all individual apps then migrate.

Comment: Yeah. But should it be like this that always have to run makemigrations individually ? It looks like sometimes it works doing general makemigrations and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: for better understanding about migration read [adding migrations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps) and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068042/django-1-8-migrations-not-detected-after-deleting-migrations-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question .

So what I have figured out . I believe the problem is that I have originally deleted the folders migrations and when I run makemigrations without specifying particular app it does create a DB but it dosent create the folder makemigrations with ____init____.py inside it.

solution each time when you drop db and delete  migrations folder for whatever reason dont just delete the migrations folder but only its content excluding init file. 
Or when you do delete the folder run make migrations individually for each app as @MicroPyramid suggested.

Without doing deeper investigation it looks to me or as confusing designed behaviour or a bug from Django side.